# How to show Minimap in Visual Studio Code (1.73.0 and above)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I show Minimap in VS Code when needed and then hide back when I don't want to use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when needed" ? Do you want to "toggle" show/hide the minimap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Mininmap:

1. Right click in verticle scroll bar as shown in image (number as 1)
2. Click on Minimap (numbered as 2)

[image: Add Minimap]

To remove Minimap:

1. Right click in shown Minimap and the uncheck the Mininmap

[image]